# Socket.IO adapter throws uncatchable Timed Out error on MongoDB disconnection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I'm trying to catch `mongodb` disconnection event.

It works fine with the following setup:

**simple.js**

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/pnsockets', function () {
    console.log('mongoose connected');
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    console.log('mongoose disconnected');
});
```

If `simple.js` is running and I stop `mongodb` (`launchctl stop homebrew.mxcl.mongodb`), I get `mongoose disconnected` on the console, and I can handle the issue.

But running `extended.js` that is usung `socket.io-adapter-mongo`, when I kill `mongodb`, I get the following error:

```
/project/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                        ^

MongoError: server localhost:27017 timed out
at null.<anonymous> (/project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:436:40)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at emit (events.js:172:7)
at null.<anonymous> (/project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:144:10)
at g (events.js:260:16)
at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
at emit (events.js:172:7)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:172:12)
at Socket.g (events.js:260:16)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at TCP._onclose (net.js:468:12)
```

**extended.js**

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var socketIO = require('socket.io');
var MongoAdapter = require('socket.io-adapter-mongo');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/pnsockets', function () {
    console.log('mongoose connected');
    _setupSocketAdapter();
});

mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    console.log('mongoose disconnected');
});


var _setupSocketAdapter = function () {
    var io = socketIO();

    var socket = mongoose.connections[0].db;
    socket.connection = mongoose.connections[0]; // mubsub will need this line

    var mongoAdapter = MongoAdapter({socket: socket});
    io.adapter(mongoAdapter);
};
```

How can I catch the `MongoError: server localhost:27017 timed out` error?

Comment: Hi, have you tried listening to the `timeout` event? Here's the line that throws that error in case you couldn't find the source: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.1/lib/mongos.js#L222

Comment: Hey @PatrickRoberts, yes, I've tried to catch all the `timeout`, `close` and `error` events, and actually I can catch the `close`, but I still got the error after, and the process exits.

Comment: Do you have the full error stack output?

Comment: Hey @YuriZarubin, thx for the comment, I've updated the question with the full error stack.

Comment: Did you try encapsulating your code in _setupSocketAdapter with try/catch block of code?

Comment: A try catch block won't work, since the error is async.

Comment: Then maybe you can try process.on('uncaughtException')

Comment: Yes, but that's not a really good solution, I'm looking for something else:)

Comment: Patrick Roberts link to source code shows that error is emited in 'connectErrorHandler' so try to listen to `connect` events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is coming from [socket.io-adapter-mongo](https://github.com/modit/socket.io-adapter-mongo) itself.

If you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/modit/socket.io-adapter-mongo/blob/master/index.js#L67), they're using [mubsub](https://github.com/scttnlsn/mubsub). Mubsub is basically a pub / sub implementation for Node.js and MongoDB.

They're setting up a client and a channel which is mapping one-to-one with a capped collection but there is no event handler attached on these parts.

According to the [mubsub documentation](https://github.com/scttnlsn/mubsub), the following event are available on a channel: `*`, `message`, `document`, `ready` and `error`. The `error` event is also available on the client.

For example, simply adding the following code would catch the errors you're having.

```
channel.on('error', function (err) {
  console.error(err.message);
});

client.on('error', function (err) {
  console.error(err.message);
});
```

In case of a disconnection, you'll get the following output instead of the unhandled error.

```
mongoose connected
server localhost:27017 timed out
mongoose disconnected
Mubsub: broken cursor.
```

Comment: Thanks, but how can I access the `channel` or `client` objects?

Comment: With the current implementation, you can't, they're not exposed, only the Adapter is returned.